# How can I fix VBA runtime error 1004 or 424

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to coding and this is my first project. I have gotten all other problems out of my way, but now I am stuck. My code is supposed to compare the entries on one sheet with the entries on a different sheet and when two conditions are met, to copy data from that row to the respective row in the other sheet. Where the data is copied exactly is based on the year which is also found in the row.

I have tried various different ways of copying data with VBA and always end up with the same two error messages:
`Runtime error 424: Object required` if I use
`Worksheets("Template").Cells(i, 4).Value.Copy`
or `Runtime error 1004: application-defined or object-defined` error when I use
`Worksheets("Template").Range(i, 4).Copy`

You can see my code below, I have left some stuff out, because it is not relevant to the problem. Also I am only posting my first two if conditions, as the other 5 are exactly the same.

```
Sub Datentransfer()

    Dim newEmptyRow As Long
    newEmptyRow = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 
0).Row
    Dim entries As Integer
    entries = Worksheets("Template").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    'Variables for runing through the two sheets
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    For i = 3 To entries 'Start in Zeile 3
        For j = 24 To newEmptyRow 'Start in Zeile 24

        'Copy if both conditions are met
        If Worksheets("Template").Cells(i, 3).Value = Worksheets("Data").Cells(j, 2).Value _
        And Worksheets("Template").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Data").Cells(j, 5).Value Then

        'Paste based on year
        If Worksheets("Template").Cells(i, 2).Value = 2011 Then
            Worksheets("Template").Range(i, 4).Copy
            Worksheets("Data").Range(j, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        ElseIf Worksheets("Template").Cells(i, 2).Value = 2012 Then
            Worksheets("Template").Range(i, 4).Copy _
            Worksheets("Data").Range(j, 9)

        End If


       End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

The error message occurs in the second row below the comment "Paste based on year."
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `Worksheets("Template").Cells(i, 4).Copy
Worksheets("Data").Cells(j, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`  .. You should change the line to this.

Comment: I have been trying to get it running for the past 24 hours and now it works. Thank you so much! Would it be possible to explain, why it works now or would I be asking too much?

Comment: I have explained in the answer. @jamieor ... If it worked than accept the answer as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain here so other users can see it too:

The problem was with the use of `Range` function. By using cells we are specifying which row and column to pick data from and where to paste.

```
Worksheets("Template").Cells(i, 4).Copy 
Worksheets("Data").Cells(j, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

`Range` is always used like `Range("A1")` or `Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,1)`. Which was not done here. There are other ways also to use Range function but these two are the most common ones.